# How to install a software on a virtual machine using custom extension script

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-powershell

i would like to install the software(.msi file) on a virtual machine using custom extension script.

Below is my powershell custom extension script.

```
$computername = 'testingpurpose'
$sourcefile = "//fossies.org/windows/misc/mysql-workbench-community-8.0.18-winx64.msi"
$destinationFolder = "\\$computername\C$\Temp"

Copy-Item -Path $sourcefile -Destination $destinationFolder 

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -ScriptBlock { Msiexec /i //fossies.org/windows/misc/mysql-workbench-community-8.0.18-winx64.msi /log C:\MSIInstall.log }
                          (or)
Start-Process -destinationFolder //fossies.org/windows/misc/mysql-workbench-community-8.0.18-winx64.msi -ArgumentList '/i',$destinationFolder,'/q' -Wait -PassThru -Verb "RunAs"
```

Comment: Could you please tell me your error message?

Comment: The DSC Extension received an incorrect input: An error occurred while executing script or module 'samplecopy.ps1': Cannot find path '//fossies.org/windows/misc/mysql-workbench-community-8.0.18-winx64.msi' because it does not exist.. Please correct the input and retry executing the extension.

Comment: `$sourcefile = "//fossies.org/windows/misc/mysql-workbench-community-8.0.18-winx64.msi"` how is this a valid url? also, you mention script extension, where as in your error you mention dsc extension?

Comment: @Awara Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, we can use `choco` to install mysql-workbench on windows Vm. For more details, please refer to the [blog](https://www.gep13.co.uk/blog/how-to-install-mysql-workbench).

My script is as below

```
iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
choco feature enable -n=allowGlobalConfirmation
choco install mysql.workbench
```